# How do i delete first 2 lines which match with a text given by me ( using sed )?

Tags: regex, shell, sed

**How do i delete first 2 lines which match with a text given by me ( using sed ! )** 

**E.g :**

```
#file.txt contains following lines :
abc
def
def
abc
abc
def
```

**And i want to delete first 2 "abc"**

Comment: Why does it have to be with sed? An awk solution would be much simpler.

Comment: I have to use sed , I just began learning shell .

Comment: To begin learning shell, step 1 is to learn which tool to use for which problem. There's a lot of ways to solve any problem in UNIX, but there's usually 1 way that's significantly better than the rest for reasons that are not obvious to beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using "sed"

While @EdMorton has pointed out that `sed` is not the best tool for this job (if you wonder why exactly, see my answer below and compare it to the `awk` code), my research showed that the solution to the generalized problem

> Delete occurences "N" through "M" of a line matching a given pattern using `sed`

indeed is a very tricky one in my opinion. There seem to be many suggestions for how to **replace** the "N"th occurence of a matching pattern with `sed`, but I found that **deleting** a specific matching **line** (or a range of lines) is a much more complex undertaking.

While the generalized problem with arbitrary values for N, M, and the pattern would probably be solved best by writing a "sed script generator" on the basis of a Finite State Machine, the solution to the special case asked by the OP is still simple enough to be coded by hand. I must admit that I wasn't very familiar with the obfuscated intricacies of the `sed` command syntax before, but I found this challenge to be quite useful for gaining more experience with non-trivial `sed` usage.

Anyway, here's my solution for deleting the first two occurences of a line containing "abc" in a file. If there's a simpler approach, I'm eager to learn about it, as this has taken me some time now.

A final caveat: this assumes GNU `sed`, as I was unable to find a solution with POSIX `sed`:

```
sed -n ':1;/abc/{n;b2;};p;$b4;n;b1;:2;/abc/{n;b3;};p;$b4;n;b2;:3;p;$b4;n;b3;:4;q' file
```

or, in more verbose syntax:

```
sed -n '
    # BEGIN - look for first match
        :first;
        /abc/ {
            # First match found. Skip line and jump to second section
            n; bsecond;
        };
        # Line does not match. Print it and quit if end-of-file reached
        p; $bend;
        # Advance to next line and start over
        n; bfirst;
    # END - look for first match

    # BEGIN - look for second match
        :second;
        /abc/ {
            # Second match found. Skip line and jump to final section
            n; bfinal;
        }
        # Line does not match. Print it and quit if end-of-file reached
        p; $bend;
        # Advance to next line and start over
        n; bsecond;
    # END - look for second match

    # BEGIN - both matches found; print remaining lines
        :final;
        # Print line and quit if end-of-file reached
        p; $bend;
        # Advance to next line and start over
        n; bfinal;
    # END - print remaining lines

    # QUIT
    :end;
    q;
' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, certainly sed isn't the best tool for this job as i can see from what you said .

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '!(/abc/ && ++c<3)' file
def
def
abc
def
```

Comment: It seems rather clear that Corneliu is asking us to do his homework, but the sed solution is 4 characters long, I wouldn't call yours simpler.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy would you care to share that 4-character sed solution with us? Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Actually I misread the question, I was thinking about `2,$p`, but it doesn't do the "matching a pattern" part. Anyway, I still think it's "do my homework" question and there's no point answering it.

Comment: @EdMorton , I can see now why  awk it's much simpler to use in this case comparing to sed , as Guido posted . 
Thanks for the tips also . 
MatthieuMoy , The point answering this is to give me a starting point for the other optional problems i want to do . I tried to do this by myself without succes and i wanted to hear other opinions .